# SQLite database creating through script

Tags: sql, sqlite

There is the following script:

```
CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS `location_cities` (
  `id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `location_region_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `location_district_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  `location_country_id` int(11) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0',
  `lon` float(11,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `lat` float(11,8) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0.00000000',
  `prefix` varchar(50) DEFAULT NULL,
  `name` varchar(128) NOT NULL,
  `size` int(3) NOT NULL DEFAULT '0' COMMENT 'Размер города',
  `tz_name` varchar(128) DEFAULT NULL,
  `timezone` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '+00:00',
  `timezone2` varchar(100) NOT NULL DEFAULT '+00:00',
  PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12393 ;
```

When I try to execute it using 'sqlite3 db/development.sqlite3 < alogist.sql' I got error 'Error: near line 27: near "AUTO_INCREMENT": syntax error' (27 - the line with "CREATE_TABLE ...". So, what's the trouble? How can I fix it? Thanks!

Comment: It's AUTOINCREMENT not 'AUTO_INCREMENT' . In SQLLite no AUTO_INCREMENT is there.

Answer (score 1):

In sqlite, an autoincrement column is specified as

```
INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT
```

Replace your `int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT` with that.

Further problems:

- `COMMENT` is not supported. Remove `COMMENT 'Размер города'`
- Remove `PRIMARY KEY (`ID`)` - the primary key has already been specified.
- Remove the MySQL-specific `ENGINE=InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8 AUTO_INCREMENT=12393`.

Answer (score 0):

SQLite syntax:

```
 `id` INTEGER PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT NOT NULL
```